# Subdomain Redirect to Secure Version

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have a subdomain, https://ssl.bkworksproducts.info - and it has a secure certificate. It's directed to the same folder as the main website - /home/USERNAME/top_domains/main_web. What I would like to do is write an .htaccess file for this folder - that determines whether its being accessed from ssl.bkworksproducts.info - and if it is, and it's not on port 443 (using the SSL Cert, or HTTP, and redirect it to HTTPS, but I don't even know where to start.

If anyone knows, kudos in advance!

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ssl\.bkworksproducts\.info$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```